# pyProcedure method which adds a new mission

Tags: python, oop

```
class Rocket:

    def __init__(self, name, mission):
        self.__name = name      
        self.__mission = mission

    def getMission(self): 
        return self.__mission
    def addMission(self, mission): 
        # procedure method which adds a new mission. There can be one (str) or multiple (list) existing missions
```

I can't understand how to implement this addMission func within a class correctly.

Output should be something like this: Missions: ['Dragon 2 pad abort test', 'Dragon 2 in-flight abort test']. What I've "come up with" simply produces the right answer if that default input is placed, albeit it has the wrong inner mechanics. Thus, with different input it won't produce a thing:

```
self.__mission = [self.__mission, mission]
```

How do I... make it work?

Comment: If I were writing this, I would ensure that the `__mission` attribute is always a list, and then use the [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method to add new items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
class Rocket:
    def __init__(self, name, mission):
        if not type(mission) in [list, tuple]:
            raise TypeError("constructor argument mission must be of type list or tuple")
        self.__name = name      
        self.__mission = mission

    def getMission(self): 
        return self.__mission
    def addMission(self, mission): 
        # procedure method which adds a new mission. There can be one (str) or multiple (list) existing missions
        if type(mission) == str:
            self.__mission.append(str)
        elif type(mission) in [list, tuple]:
                self.__mission.extend(miss)
        else:
            raise TypeError("addMission argument mission must have types str, list or tuple")
```

Comment: Better use `collections.MutableSequence` for checking the type. It ensures that the `mission` has the `.append()` method implemented. E.g. `if isinstance(mission, MutableSequence):`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence.

Also, instead of appending one item at a time, it's better to use `mission.extend()`

Comment: Thanks @Icebreaker454 for your advice, learnt something new myself !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work =(

```
def addMission(self, mission): 
    if isinstance(mission, str) is True:
        [self.__mission].append(mission)
    elif isinstance(mission, list) is True:
        [self.__mission].extend(mission)
```

As result I have only 1 value from getMission(). Second value doesn't add to list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. SO is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. The answer section is reserved for answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).